# z-index of pseudo elements changes during -webkit-transition: opacity

Tags: html, css, webkit, z-index, css-transitions

I am using -webkit-transition to animate the opacity of an element that has an absolutely positioned pseudo element. The trouble is that the pseudo element is supposed to appear behind  the element, but during the transition it appears in front. You can [see it in action here](http://tinker.io/c4977/20). What can I do to keep it in the back?

Comment: which div should be behind which div ?

Comment: the pink one should always be in the back